# Adding local css/js files from asset folder to remote web page

Tags: android

I have an Android webView which loads a remote web page. As the code of this page is controlled by a colleague I can ask him to change it but I would prefer to find a solotion totally on client side.

For reasons regarding traffic and performance we want to store our css and javascript files locally on the client and not load them from the server.

What I came up with are two ideas but none of them worked out so far.

1. Store all the files in the asset folder and have the html refer to them

   Problem: The webview seems to be not allowed to access "file:///..." urls

   Question: Is there a way to work around this issue?
2. Just ignore all those references in the html and just inject all those files after loading them in the webview

   Question: Just how do I add those files (.css / .js) to my already loaded html?

Answer (score 2):

## You can build a local WebView in the following way

- The Activity (LocalWebviewActivity.java)
- The Layout (activity_localwebview.xml)
- The Assets folder (in the root of "assets" folder, create the folder "css" and place "style.css" in here)
- You refer to JS files the same way you refer to CSS StyleSheets

### LocalWebviewActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class LocalWebviewActivity extends Activity {

    WebView myWebView;
    StringBuilder mySBcontent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_localwebview);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webkit);
        mySBcontent = new StringBuilder();

        mySBcontent.append("<html>");
        mySBcontent.append("<head>");
        mySBcontent.append("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>");
        mySBcontent.append("</head>");
        mySBcontent.append("<body>");
        mySBcontent.append("<h1>My Heading</h1>");
        mySBcontent.append("<p>My HTML content</p>");
        mySBcontent.append("<p><img style='width:150px;' src='myImg.png' /></p>");
        mySBcontent.append("</body>");
        mySBcontent.append("</html>");

        myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", mySBcontent.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
    }
}
```

### activity_localwebview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webkit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But then I will have to provide ALL the relatively referenced files in my app (images, links etc. as well as the script files) and furthermore have to much more explicitly manipulate the given html which ideally would not even be known in the app as it is maintained by a different project team.

Comment: @Benjamin K, Can you elaborate more on what you want to store locally on your device (css/js) and what you want to store remotely (html?) ?

Comment: I have a web-application on a sever which I have to integrate into a native app via webview. The web-application provides dynamically generated html pages which make use of various static css files, images and .js files (jquery mobile for example). To improve the performance and  avoid uneccessary data traffic the plan is to store those static files on the device instead of loading them from the server.

BUT: It is required to keep the possibility to add .css and .js files dynamically which are NOT stored on the device. Thus, using you (usually very helpful) solution would not work.

Comment: .css file works.. but javascript file is not working

Comment: you can try using :https://github.com/google/webview-local-server. I am still to try this. But looks promising